# How to define an Emacs command that uses `replace-string` for a specific string

Tags: regex, emacs

In Emacs, I am processing a text document, converting from unicode plaintext to LaTeX.

There are a few sets of regular expressions that I want to run, for example

```
M-x replace-string ± RET \pm RET
M-x replace-string µ RET  \textmu
```

How do I save these regular expressions so that I can run them repeatedly?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the full story here, but have you considered switching to a TeX engine that supports unicode?  I've found XeLaTeX to be an excellent alternative.

Comment: I have been using xelatex and they still don't show up. For example, I tried to render


± is $\pm$

and the first didn't show up

Comment: What font are you using? It could be that only your math font has the ± glyph.  I tried it with minion pro and it worked fine entered as unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally like writing custom commands, here's the one for your first replacement:

```
(defun replace-plus-minus ()
  (interactive)
  (replace-string "±" "\\pm" nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

But, you can also use keyboard macros.  Check out the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) and [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html).

Basically, you'd do:

```
C-x ( M-x replace-string ± RET \pm RET C-x )
```

Then you can name it, and save it to your .emacs:

```
M-x name-last-kbd-macro
M-x insert-kbd-macro
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the custom command howto. The trouble I was having with macro recording was that I am not sure how to use my keyboard to enter in the ± character. I was just pasting it in from somewhere else. And, pasting it in from somewhere else killed the recording of the macro, or at least made it so that it didn't do what I wanted it to.

Comment: Pasting should work, so long as Emacs is receiving the *pasted* characters, and not the "paste this" command characters (or mouse clicks). How you do that depends on your environment (but running `emacs -nw` in a shell may make it easier).

Comment: Or even easier, just enter any place-holder character instead when recording the macro, and then type `C-x C-k e RET RET` to edit the macro, and change the place-holder to the correct character. Within the editor you do not have the constraints of recording, so you can happily yank or paste things.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a [macro](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros)?

Once you've created a macro you can also [save it](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html) to your .emacs file
Additionally you can run M-x replace-string and just hit enter twice and it will run your last command.

Comment: Thanks. I did try working on a macro, but see my comments to the other answer for why that was not working.

Comment: You may have to make sure the file  supports unicode: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnicodeEncodingFind. Then find the right emacs key combination to get that character (or just pasting in in should work). You could also just run the macro with a temporary character, save it to your bash using the above, and then modify the macro (it's at the bottom of your .emacs file once you save.)