# How to define an Emacs command to “query-replace-regexp” using a specific regexp

Tags: regex, emacs

I am trying to add a command to my `init` file but neither of this things seems to work:

- [How to define an Emacs command that uses `replace-string` to replace a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446913/how-can-i-save-a-regex-as-a-custom-defun-in-emacs)
- [How to define an Emacs command that uses `replace-string` for a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843339/in-emacs-how-to-save-regular-expressions/5843955#5843955)

I want to save this regex:

```
Query replace regexp (default \([A-Z]\{3,\} ?[A-Z]+\) -> `\1`)
```

In my `init` file I have tried to add:

```
(defun to-inline-code ()
   (interactive)
   (query-replace-regexp 
       "\([A-Z]\{3,\} ?[A-Z]+\)"
       "`\1`" 
       nil 
       1
       (point-marker) (point-max)))
```

But it does not work, when I execute `to-inline-code`.

I've also tried:

```
(defun to-inline-code ()
   (interactive)
   (query-replace-regexp 
       "\([A-Z]\{3,\} ?[A-Z]+\)"
       "`\1`" ))
```

Whith the same luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the backslashes in the strings:

```
(defun to-inline-code ()
   (interactive)
   (query-replace-regexp 
       "\\([A-Z]\\{3,\\} ?[A-Z]+\\)"
       "`\\1`" 
       nil 
       1
       (point-marker) (point-max)))
```

i.e. write `\\` for each `\`.

On `xy ABCD CC 5` this gives it matches one expression and answering yes gives

```
xy A`BCD CC` 5
```

which may or may not be what you are looking for.  I suspect you need a slight different regexp.

You can see the longer form of the command in the minibuffer by typing the interactive verison `C-M-% ....` (i.e. `M-x query-replace-regexp`) and then asking to repeat that command with `C-x ESC ESC` (i.e. `M-x repeat-complex-command`).

Comment: Thanks!, that was the problem.